# Extend SP 2010 Picture Library Slideshow webpart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-query-web-part, picture-library

I have picture library at the root site which feeds input for OOTB Picture Library slideshow webpart. I have a requirement to have Slideshow webpart on subsites as well with the same pool of pictures (with some exception determined by field value). As this webpart has access to picture library at its site level, I am trying to come up with  solution where any slideshow webpart can source pictures from same picture library at the root site. Apart from easy solution of creating picture library on each site, I have come across quick solution extending CQWP, JQuery, CSS and XSL which works great! but looses out some of controls users get in OOTB slideshow web part. Is it possible to extend slideshow webpart to allow any picture library within current site collection?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[Picture Library SlideShow web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.picturelibraryslideshowwebpart.aspx) class is marked a **sealed**, so there is no way to extend it in order to retrieve pictures from site collection.

---

But it could be accomplished via CQWP, the idea here is to render Slideshow the same way as it is rendered via [Picture Library SlideShow web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.picturelibraryslideshowwebpart.aspx)

So,the solution consists of the following steps:

- create XSL template for rendering Slideshow Html and utilize Slideshow control (imglib.js)
- configure source properties (`List Type: Picture Library, Content Type:  Picture`)

Figure 1. Slideshow control hosted in CQWP
[image]

---

For more details follow the example *Aggregate picture items and render as Slideshow* in [this](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/04/27/beyond-the-slideshow-web-part-capabilities-in-sharepoint-2010/) post